# Is there a command line to deploy a SQL Server database project?

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio-2010

We are using the *SQL Server Database* project template with Visual Studio 2010. As part of our integration testing, I would like to first launch a fresh deploy of the database. But short of manually right clicking the project and picking "Deploy", it doesn't seem to be a simple thing to get a fresh copy of the database deployed.

The documentation for this project type seems sparse to non-existent. Perhaps I"m looking in the wrong place. If possible, please include a reference to the how-to.

Update:

Our integration tests are written as unit tests in Visual Studio.  So the goal would be to press the <kbd>Run Tests</kbd> button, and have the database deploy, and then the tests against it run.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I managed to find a command line tool to do this. It's called VSDBCMD.EXE and it comes with Visual Studio 2010. I first learned about it [here (scroll to the bottom of the article)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff678491.aspx#deploy), then I followed a [link and found the details of how to get it installed on my server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd193258.aspx).

In the second article, if you're on a 64 bit machine, you won't find the VSTSDB directory under Program Files... you'll need to look under Program Files (x86).

I followed the instructions to the letter (installed both the 32-bit and 64-bit version of SQL CE) and it's working great. I basically take the output of a build from my SQL Server 2008 database project, zip it up and put it on the server, then run the deploy script.

The first time I did this, the target database didn't exist. The tool created the database and set it up nicely. Then I tried adding a column to a table in my project. I rebuilt the project and took the output and deployed as before, and it correctly altered the existing table, just like it would have done by right-clicking and selecting Deploy.

Seems to be working well so far. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 5):

For a fresh database instance (not an incremental update to a database), MSDeploy should do the trick.  [Here's](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vstsdb/thread/563d0f91-49d3-42cb-ac5d-b57833ddc5c6) a quick post I found on the subject.  I haven't actually done it myself yet, but a collegue says it's worked in his environment.

Answer (score 3):

I am running this in Powershell:

```
&"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\MSBuild\Current\Bin\MSBuild.exe" /t:Build,Publish /p:SqlPublishProfilePath="C:\Path-To-Project\My-Local-Database.xml" "D:\Path-To-Project\My.Database.sqlproj"
```

- MSBuild is not in the path, so I added the full path.
- Instead of using a ; to separate the targets I used a comma as this doesn't break Powershell.
- I am using Publish to publish to my local DB and the settings are in the XML file which is saved from the Publish screen in Visual Studio.
- The default target is Build, when you specify Publish it does not run the default target, so you have to specify both Build and Publish.
- Should also work in a command window if you remove the '&' at the start.

Answer (score 2):

According to this MSDN article [How to: Deploy Changes to New or Existing Databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa833271%28v=vs.100%29.aspx), you should be able to use MSBuild for that:

```
MSBuild /t:Build;Deploy c:\path-to-my-project\DatabaseProject.dbproj
```